# ansible ребут серверов по очереди

Tags: ansible

Добрый день, господа.

Задача следующая: 
запустить ребут сервера && подождать пока он поднимется && ребут следующего сервера и по кругу

думал использовать
ansible -a 'reboot' serverstoupdate - но это все сервера будут в даунтайме, что не позволительно.

Подскажите, как реализовать задуманное? 
Как плейбуком? 
Может дадите ссылку на документацию?

Comment: Вообще-то ансибл придуман для того, чтобы один и тот же плейбук запускать паралельно на всех серверах, а не ждать пока последовательно один за другим выполнится. Сейчас подумаю, как можно выкрутиться из этой ситуации. Но во-первых, вот вам один из фрагментов вашего вопроса: [как определить, что сервер поднялся](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877781/how-to-wait-for-server-restart-using-ansible) Кроме того, ничего вам не запрещает в команде reboot указывать разное плановое время рестарта, м? ) Скажем, с интервалом в 10 минут -- должно за глаза хватить на рестарт.

Comment: Благодарю за наведение на истину.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Плейбуком с использованием `serial`:

```
---
- hosts: serverstoupdate
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - name: Restart machine
      shell: sleep 2 && shutdown -r now "Ansible reboot"
      async: 20
      poll: 0

    - name: Waiting for SSH to come up
      become: no
      local_action: wait_for host={{ inventory_hostname }} port=22 delay=20 timeout=300 search_regex=OpenSSH
```

Будет по очереди (serial: 1) отправлять команду на перезапуск, через 20 секунд (delay=20) начинать проверять отвечает ли sshd, после этого переходить к следующему серверу.

Comment: Можно подробнее о serial?

Comment: Есть описание в документации: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size

Comment: Красивое решение.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо. А ссылку еще на       описание async  и     poll можно?

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_async.html

Comment: Также в хостах есть на некоторых серверах ansible_port=56777   - как быть?

Comment: В моем ответе достаточно информации, чтобы решить и этот вопрос.